# What's puppeteer api for `document.elementFromPoint`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, chromium, puppeteer

ElementFromPoint is described in MDN, but I couldn't find a similar function in Puppeteer.

I am aware that I can execute my code as `page.$eval`, but I was wondering if there's a direct `page.elementFromPoint` API.

MDN docs link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no Puppeteer function explicitly built for [`DocumentOrShadowRoot.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint), but you can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to execute this functionality directly in the page DOM environment:

```
await page.evaluate( () => {
    const example = document.elementFromPoint( 100, 100 );
    example.style.color = '#f00';
});
```

If you need to click or tap an element at specific coordinates, you can use [`mouse.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#mouseclickx-y-options) or [`touchscreen.tap()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#touchscreentapx-y):

```
await page.mouse.click( 100, 100 );
await page.touchscreen.tap( 100, 100 );
```

Comment: With variables outside:
await page.evaluate( (x, y) => {
    const example = document.elementFromPoint( x, y );
    example.style.color = '#f00';
}, 100, 100);